# Sistering floor joists with lvl

Tags: floor, joists, lumber

I am going to sister a few of 2x8 floor joists (70 yrs old) with lvl. I know I can use same size dimensional lumber but why not to use lvl to get better reinforcement. Cost is fine. Any input appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there isn't a question here.

Comment: Not every post requires a question Mark. Some are implied questions. This is a good example.

Comment: the part that says "but why not to use lvl to get better reinforcement." is missing a question mark. I can forgive that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Generally the easiest/cheapest and most understood thing is to sister with dimensional and that is probably going to be the default go-to for most contractors.

LVL is thicker 1.75" vs 1.5" and when you are sistering you want the fasteners to go all the way through both members, in your case this is 3.25" so you are still good with a framing nailer.  When you do multiple LVL together it gets trickier as you are then looking at 3.5" thickness and most nail guns aren't pushing out 3.5" fasteners.

What are the support points for your newly sistered joists?  Are they hangers or do they sit on something?  If they need hangers what is your plan, double dimensional hangers will not be wide enough, double lvl will be too wide.  I've seen people just throw a filler wedge into the gap where a double hanger was too wide.

LVLs are also harder to drill and have different rules for notching/boring and drilling so when you couple them up with dimensional you are going to either be limited to the lowest common denominator in terms of drilling / notching area or you are going to have to get sign off from an engineer or just half ass it.

Will you have the lumber yard rip the lvl to the same height as your 70 yo dimensional joists?  Are they 8" nominal or actual 8"?  Can you get LVL in the same depth?

Those are some considerations you should make.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. My joists sit on the sill plate and mid span beam- no hangers needed.  However, good point- i need to ensure old lumber and new lvl to have same depth-not sure if it is possible- I will check